# Docker in production with a CI tool

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

what's the best way to run a dockerized application in production while using a CI tool?
I've been using docker-compose in development but now I need a workflow for production, include updating my services.

For now I have one versionned folder containing all the services needed by the application to run (each service is in its own subfolder and has a dockerfile). The issue is, for example if I update the backend I'd like to deploy and restart only that service and not all the services.

The application with its services will be running on only one machine. No need for replicas or multiple nodes.

Any resource giving a deep explanation of the solution would be very appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [drone](https://github.com/drone/drone) to control your CI workflow.

I suppose all your services are controlled by a git repo. Then follow the guide of [GitFlow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), create different branch for each service.

When you done your update, add some commit on your `service/A` branch, then creare a PR to `dev` branch. At this time, drone [docker plugin](http://plugins.drone.io/drone-plugins/drone-docker/) will build your docker image, and push image to docker registry. Example drone config will look like:

```
steps:  
  - name: build-image 
    image: plugins/docker  
    settings:  
      repo: your-image-repo-on-docker-registry
      username:   
      password:     
    when:  
      branch: dev  
      event: pull_request
  - name: deploy-container
    image: appleboy/drone-scp
    settings:
      host: yourserver.com
      username: ubuntu
      password: ssh_password
      port: 22
      script:
      - docker-compose pull your-image-repo-on-docker-registry
      - docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thank you @meya. 
For now the entire project is in one git repo. Is this a good practice for production?
I'll take a look at Drone

Comment: If want to share code between service, it is convenient. But be careful to test your code when share code has modify.

Comment: No. I didn't want to share the code. It's just I was using a mono repo because of docker-compose